# PHP Laravel Select Query

Tags: php, laravel, select, null

```
foreach ($task as $task1) {
    $parent=\DB::select('select parent_wbs_id from projwbs where wbs_id= "$task1->wbs_id"');        
            foreach ($parent as $parent1){
            \DB::table('tasks')->insert([
            ['id'=>$task1->task_id, 'text'=>$task1->task_name, 'start_date'=>$task1->act_start_date, 
                'duration'=>round($days), 'parent'=>$parent1->parent_wbs_id,'progress'=>1.0]
               ]);
            }
            
            
        }
```

My parent select query has **where clause** in which it is checking **wbs_id** from **for each loop** of task and getting **parent_wbs_id** accordingly.

Now, the question is-- It is not going inside my inside **parent loop** and I am stuck If It is returning an empty row to **$parent**.

And I tried displaying **$parent**. It prompted me with an error of invalid array to string conversion

Sorry, I have just started PHP laravel project and I am a beginner in this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```php
foreach ($task as $task1) {
    // $parent=\DB::select('select parent_wbs_id from projwbs where wbs_id= "$task1->wbs_id"'); 

    $parent = \DB::table('projwbs')
                  ->where('wbs_id', $task1->wbs_id)
                  ->select('parent_wbs_id')
                  ->get();

    // $parent should contains all parent_wbs_id from table projwbs where wbs_id is equal to $task1->wbs_id
}
```

The main error in your first query was you didn't use `get` at the end, so you were iterating through a query builder.

Also, you can't use `select` the way you did, I rewrote it with the way Laravel expects.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting your solution!